# Is there any js radar chart library can work with Tuespechkin on console application?

Tags: c#, chart.js, console-application, wkhtmltopdf, tuespechkin

I am trying to develop an .Net console application that can convert an html file (with css, js file) to pdf by Tuespechkin.

There is an radar chart in html file. That radar chart show smoothly in browser (even IE 11). But chart cannot show in pdf file.

Something is strange. There is an error on console screen, but pdf file was created.

`Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80010106)`

How can I solved my situation?

Is there any js radar chart library can work with Tuespechkin on console application?

If you did it, Please tell me!

Comment: In short rendering html to pdf is not a trivial task, Tuespechkin has limitations, so do many other solutions, however, i cant think of any that would fully render javascript css to pdf, there are just too many degrees of freedom. Though you will just have to go and search as many as you can and try them out

Answer (score 0):

At last, i found this js radar chart library can work with Tuespechkin.
For anyone need this.

http://bl.ocks.org/chrisrzhou/2421ac6541b68c1680f8